# Python/Django Patching/Mocking a functions current decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, decorator

I saw you posting around decorators. I am having a hard time finding out how to Mock a decorator. Most searches show me how to write a decorate to help tes, but to be clear, I already have decorators and when I am unittesting a function that HAS a decorator I would like to mock it so its response is not part of the test.

Any guidance?

Comment: Maybe it's the second glass of Scotch I'm on - but that really doesn't make much sense to me.  Can you try to clarify what you're after?

Comment: You can certainly mock a decorator. Post some example code that we can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock a decorator.  A decorator replaces your function at compile time with the decorated function.  If a function is decorated, you cannot test that function without the decorator without pulling the guts of the function out into another (non-decorated) function.